# Sycing Data in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I am creating an application that users can input data and that data is sent to a SQL server I am hosting via JSON. I would like for users to be able to use the software offline and have the data resynced when the device reaches another connection. What is the best method for doing this with swift?

Comment: Save that JSON locally as a file or in database. Sync it when network connection is available and remove it from local device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done similar things in one of my apps.

I had a local database powered by coreData

And so the distant Database On a SQL Server.

When the user had internet i check in my local database which data are unsynced, and I send them to the distant Database.
For that CoreData is Powerful since you can easily have 2 contexts (one for synced data, and the second for unsynced datas)
BUT CoreData IS NOT a relation Database, like SQL. It use an Object approach so if you want to use it, keep that in mind.

Note:
1) Depends how your server is build but in a system with 2 databases like that you could have some conflict. You need to think of how to handle it soon.
You will have conflicts when downloading some datas, and when uploading...

2)Obviously, You shouldn't add data on the SQL Server directly from the app. You need a JSON API.

3) I am not saying that CoreData is the best way to do that. Maybe using a sqlite Database can be easier. Depends if you had already use CoreData in iOS.

Comment: I'm most likely going to have to do it with a sqlite database... I haven't been using CoreData, and to be honest it confused me, but it is still a possibility. Especially in future versions.